# Social media integration for android

Tags: android, social-networking

I need to integrate some social media like **facebook,twitter,linked in,pin interest,google,google plus etc..**

so far as i have used **social auth.jar** file but i don't know about security level and also i am counldn't ping with **pin interest**.

if any other way to integrate social networking without socialauth like http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

or use http://ogp.me/ concept

If you have any idea please share with me

Answer (score 0):

use this libs :

[ASNE library](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE)

[Android-Simple-Social-Sharing](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Simple-Social-Sharing)

OR

[Read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr) !